# How to find $plusargs with same string in different locations

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Very general issue in large integration of verification environment.
Our verification development involves large group across different time zone.
Group has preference to use $plusargs instead factory mechanism.
Probably main reason it is hard to set factory from command line processor,
we have more layers of scripts to start simulation.
Recently i found that same string been used in different environment to control behavior of environment. In this case two different score board used same string to disable some checking and test pass. Both those environment some time created at run time. Also some time it is OK to re-use same string, and it will require owner to be involved.
Is there any way to find duplication like this from final elaborated model, and provide locations in code as a warning?

I thought create our own wrapper, but problem that we are integrating some code that we are not owners as in this case was.
Thanks,

Comment: It is a very vague description of your problem. You should add an example to make it more clear and remove all  unneeded info about the team collaborations. $plusargs searches command line arguments in one order and returns the first match. What does 'different locations' mean? which tool do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example of how people think they can get things done quicker by not following the recommended UVM methodology and instead create time consuming complexity later on.

I see at least two possible options.

1. Write a script that searches the source code for `$plusargs` and hopefully they have used string literals for you to trace for duplicates.
2. You can override `$plusargs` with PLI code and have it trace duplicates.

The choice depends on wether you are better at writing Perl/Python or C code.